# Как ограничить sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(), чтобы в предсказании не выдавала отрицательные значения?

Tags: python, python-3.6, sklearn

Как ограничить `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()`, чтобы в предсказании не выдавала отрицательные значения?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, напрямую этого нельзя сделать, но можно обработать результат, выдаваемый регрессией, с помощью функции `numpy.clip`:

```
import numpy as np

np.clip([1, -2, 2, -1], 0, None)
```

Вывод:

```
array([1, 0, 2, 0])
```